# R - Unexpected output when running a function on a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm writing a function that computes a new column based on several fields in my data frame. Part of the process is to do a pre-check on the range of one the input fields before actual processing. Weird thing is that my pre-check *always* returns the same value, that is, the outcome of the pre-check for the first row of the dataframe.

See example below with a simplified version of my function, which only includes the check. Even though the variable is properly passed to the function, and is different every time, the outcome of the pre-check stays the same. What am I missing?

```
> my_function = function(x){
+   print(paste(x, x < 32 && x > 0))
+   if (x < 32 && x > 0) {
+     # do_something ...
+   }
+ }
> 
> df = data.frame("A" = c(10,20,30,40), "B" = c(0,10,20,30), "C" = c(40,30,20,10))
> my_function(df$A)
[1] "10 TRUE" "20 TRUE" "30 TRUE" "40 TRUE"
> my_function(df$B)
[1] "0 FALSE"  "10 FALSE" "20 FALSE" "30 FALSE"
> my_function(df$C)
[1] "40 FALSE" "30 FALSE" "20 FALSE" "10 FALSE"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need vectorised `ifelse` with a single `&` (instead of `&&`) if you want to test a condition on every element of a vector.

From `?ifelse`

> ‘ifelse’ returns a value with the same shape as ‘test’ which is
>        filled with elements selected from either ‘yes’ or ‘no’ depending
>        on whether the element of ‘test’ is ‘TRUE’ or ‘FALSE’.

From `` ?`&&` ``

> ‘&’ and ‘&&’ indicate logical AND and ‘|’ and ‘||’ indicate
>        logical OR.  The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in
>        much the same way as arithmetic operators.  The longer form
>        evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each
>        vector.  Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined.
>        The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and
>        typically preferred in ‘if’ clauses.

The short form `&` performs an element-wise comparison, while `&&` evaluates only the first element of the vector.

---

Here is an example based on your `df`

```
f1 <- function(x) if (x < 32 && x > 0) x + 100 else x - 100;
f2 <- function(x) ifelse(x < 32 & x > 0, x + 100, x - 100);

f1(df$A)
#[1] 110 120 130 140

f2(df$A)
#[1] 110 120 130 -60
```

Comment: Down-voter please explain the reason for down-voting. Happy to elaborate more if my post is not clear; this *does* solve OPs question (and was accepted as an answer) so the down-vote seems unwarranted.

Comment: @RHertel I appreciate the feedback; however OPs question is *not* about how to return a `TRUE`/`FALSE` vector; if you read the question carefully you'll notice that OPs `my_function` signifies a more complex (unknown to us) routine **which requires element-wise comparison of values in a vector**; therefore the issue is in fact with `ifelse` and the use of a single `&`; in order for answers to be useful for others here on SO, they should be generalisable to different/related problems. I admit that my example was somewhat "clumsy", I'll make a change to fix that. Downvote is still unwarrated.